# How to link to a local .html-file in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, html, gatsby

I have a Gatsby-website, and I want to link to a file called index.html which contains a regular html page with some javascript. Everything I've read leads me to believe that the following should work, but it does not (I just reach a 404-page):

- create a folder called "static" under the "src"-folder in my gatsby project
- put index.html inside that folder
- link to index.html by using  `<a href="/static/index.html"> go to index.html </a>`

Anyone have any ideas to why this won't work? I've tried both in development and after pushing the site to be "live" (it builds fine, just won't reach index.html in either case).

What I want to happen is that gatsby treats the link like it would if index.html was for an external site, I want the link to open the html file in a new tab and just run it as a normal non-gatsby site would be run.

**Updated info regarding progress garnered from comments:**

I've now tried to direct the link to /index.html, and that leads me to a blank, white page. It's not 404, but it's not the real index.html in the static-folder either since I still reach the blank white page even if I remove index.html. I have also tried this with a minimal html-file with just one line of text and the most basic bare-bones html-code, Gatsby can't find that one either.

Extra info:

Gatsby CLI version: 5.11.0

Gatsby version: 5.11.0

Comment: Have you tried /index.html ? Also you will need to add target="_blank" to your anchor to open in a new tab.

Comment: Have you tried /index.html ?

Comment: /index.html (with and without target="_blank") seems to have done something! I'm now linked to a blank white site (the site is supposed to run a three.js tutorial-script and render a 3d ball). It's progress but not all the way, I'm guessing it doesn't want to run the external "three.min.js" script that's included in the folder with index.html

Comment: Clarification: I get the result of a white page on navigating to /index.html regardless of whether or not there's an actual index.html file present in the static-folder, so the actual real index.html still doesn't seem to be found or run

Comment: None, I've shifted focus to just trying to run a simple hello-world type html-file, so now the folder structure looks like "src\static\index.html"